# Is there a way to remove the header and footer from a custom made homepage?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web

I've created a custom home page/landing page for my site, which is totally different from the rest of the site. Now, my only problem is that the header and footer appear, and I only just want what I coded to appear. I've tried with site origin's custom css, but I don't know my home page's ID.

So, how can I remove the header and footer with custom css or is there any other better way to do this.

Comment: Depending on the version of Wordpress and the way the template is made, and assuming you created it via WP backoffice, you can perhaps add a new meta data to pages and use it to set a specific value for the landing page and then in the page template set the logic to skip the header/footer for this specific one. On the other hand, if you made a new page template just for the landing page, just ommit the inclusion of the header and footer and create custom HTML wrapper for it. Not sure if I hit the subject, but I hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this, I would assume:

```
#header, #footer{
    display: none;
}
```

Of course, you'll need to swap out `#header` and `#footer` for the actual `class` / `id` of the elements.

Comment: Thanx a lot. It's so simple and yet I've been struggling for the past few hours.

Comment: @Z5678 that's ok :) be sure to select my answer as solved your problem, and upvote it if you're feeling generous ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the html of the footer and header?..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this in your page stylesheet:

```
#header, #footer{
    display: none !important;
}
```

// note that you will need to substitute the name of the id #yourheaderid, #yourfooterid.

If you used `<footer>` and `<header` tags you can do

```
header, footer{
        display: none !important;
    }
```

if you have a class name on your footer and header you do this:

```
.header, .footer{
            display: none !important;
        }
```